# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' when parsing json

Tags: swift3

I just updated to Xcode 8.0/Swift 3 and I'm getting this message

> Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

on this line:

let rootResults = **rootDictionary["results"]** as? [[NSObject: AnyObject]]

The rest of the code is shown below:

```
func parseJSON(data: NSData) {
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: .mutableContainers)
        if let rootDictionary = json as? [NSObject: AnyObject],
            let rootResults = rootDictionary["results"] as? [[NSObject: AnyObject]]
        {

            for childResults in rootResults {

                if let firstName = childResults["first_name"]! as? String {
                    let customerFirstName = firstName
                    customerData["firstName"] = customerFirstName
                }
                if let lastName = childResults["middle_name"]! as? String {
                    let customerLastName = lastName
                    customerData["middleName"] = customerLastName
                }
                if let lastName = childResults["last_name"]! as? String {
                    let customerLastName = lastName
                    customerData["lastName"] = customerLastName
                }
                if let nameSuffix = childResults["name_suffix"]! as? String {
                    let customerSuffix = nameSuffix
                    customerData["nameSuffix"] = customerSuffix
                }

            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I have looked at other questions similar to this but they are about something unrelated to json parsing.
I would appreciate any help on this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift 3, most implicit type conversions are removed.
That has made String literals unable to be automatically converted to `NSObject`.

Try replacing `[NSObject: AnyObject]` in your code to `[String: AnyObject]`.