# Swift 3 and Xcode 8.2 - Ambiguous reference to member 'Subscript'

Tags: swift, xcode, reference, ambiguous, subscript

I get a error and I do not know why ... can anyone help me? I am despairing!
No other post has helped me. Thank you very much in advance for your answer!!

PS: I get the error only when I try to run on my own iphone

[Image with Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C9hX.jpg)

```
func parseJson() {
    let username: String = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "username")! as! String
    let url=URL(string:"https://website.de")
    do {
        let allBetData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let allBet = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allBetData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]


        if let arrJSON = allBet["bets"] as! [String : AnyObject]? {
            for index in 0...arrJSON.count-1 {



                let aObject = arrJSON[index] as [String : AnyObject]?

                header.append(aObject["header"] as! String)
                rowDescription.append(aObject["rowDescription"] as! String)
                bodytext.append(aObject["bodytext"] as! String)
            }
        }



        print("data loaded")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    catch {
        self.logout()
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' when parsing json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427214/ambiguous-reference-to-member-subscript-when-parsing-json)

Comment: Please post the code instead of a link.

Comment: You're declaring a variable as a dictionary and then you're using this variable as if it were an array. This doesn't work, *as expected*... // Post the code in your question, not an image of code.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not follow

Comment: Can someone help me in form of a code snippet

Comment: Make `arrJSON` an array: `... as [[String:AnyObject]]?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is **totally fundamental** and you need to **make sure you get this**.

One line at a time...

```
if let arrJSON = allBet["bets"] as! [String : AnyObject]? {
```

Here you say, "I am making this thing called arrJSON, it's a dictionary with **string keys** and any sort of value". Good so far? Then you...

```
for index in 0...arrJSON.count-1 {
```

"I would like to loop the number of times that there are items"...

```
 let aObject = arrJSON[index] as [String : AnyObject]?
```

"...and get the object who's key is **this number**".

Do you understand the problem now?