# Ambiguous reference to member subscript with Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>

Tags: swift

I am getting this "Ambiguous reference to member subscript" error for below code -

```
let resultsDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

let items: Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>> = resultsDict["items"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>
```

Comment: How you declare resultsDict

Comment: let resultsDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

Comment: One of the problem that you are using force cast. Try to add if let check to this step and you will find out if it Dictionary type

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk If you read the code you can see the declaration of `resultsDict`. And the issue has nothing to do with force casting. The issue is with casting to the wrong types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' when parsing json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427214/ambiguous-reference-to-member-subscript-when-parsing-json)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would not use `NSObject` with `JSONSerialization`, use `[AnyHashable: Any]` or `[String : Any]` instead.  Secondly, I would recommend you use the shorthand dictionary and array syntax with brackets.  I would also recommend using safe downcasts (`as ?`) with `if let` instead of forced downcasts (`as!`) for safety.

```
do {
    if let resultsDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String : Any] {

        let items = resultsDict["items"] as? [[String : Any]]
        // use items
    }
} catch {
    // handle error
}
```